# Eclipse Helios PHP outline view is empty

Tags: php, eclipse, outline-view

Using Eclipse Helios, my PHP outline view is showing some very strange behavior in all new workspaces that I create.

In my initial work space with eclipse projects, the outline view is working fine.  I can switch between files and projects, the new outline is displayed in the view, as one would expect.

In all other work spaces with new PHP projects that I've created the outline view is empty for all PHP files except the one that was the main focus.   So, when I launch Eclipse, select my workspace, the PHP file that was the last one open before I closed, is displayed and it's outline is correct.  If I close the file and reopen it, they outline is no longer displayed.

My Quick-Outline (ctrl-o) works fine on all files.

Here are the things I've checked.

1. My file extensions are .php
2. Eclipse is recognizing my syntax, it points out errors, it gives type-ahead suggestions, all other behavior seems normal.
3. My source is in my build path, and it is included, excluded is set to (none)
4. My "Link with Editor" property is set, checking and unchecking it does not help
5. Build automatically is set, and initiating "project/clean" does not help
6. Both my "Filters" and "Filters..." settings inside outline have nothing excluded, all settings are

There is an interesting note between the two views, when they work vs, when they don't work.   The icons and menu items in different orders.

The view buttons are:
working: 1.Collapse, 2.sort, 3.link, 4.focus, 5.view menu
non-working: 1.Focus, 2.collapse, 3.sort, 4.link, 5.View menu

The view menu 
Working:1.Link,2.Show Attributes,3.PHP(checked),4.HTML,5.Filters...,6.Filters,7.Focus
Non-Working:1. Filters, 2.Focus,3.Link,4.Show Attributes,5.PHP(checked),6.HTML,7.Filters...

Both workspaces are being launched from the same windows shortcut, with prompting for workspace directory name.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by reverting back to a previous entry in my installation history.  All seems to work now.